# Передача get данных в Angular 4+

Tags: c#, angular2, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть API на asp.net core 2.0 и приложение на Angular 4+. Проблема в том, что api отдает информацию, но angular не производит вывод. Не могу понять в чем проблема. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код контроллера:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<OcItem> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.ocItems.ToArray();
    }
```

app.component.ts:

```html
import {TemplateRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OcService } from './oc.service';
import { Oc } from './Oc';
import {Headers, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  providers: [OcService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('readOnlyTemplate') readonlyTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('editTemplate') editTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  editedOc: Oc;
  ocs: Array<Oc>;
  isNewRecord: boolean;
  statusMessage: string;

  constructor(private serv: OcService){
    this.ocs = new Array<Oc>();
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.loadOc();
  }

  //Загрузка списка
  private loadOc(){
    this.serv.getOc().subscribe((resp: Response) =>{
      this.ocs = resp.json();
      console.log(resp);
    })
  }
```

oc.service.ts:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Oc } from './Oc';

@Injectable()
export class OcService{
    private url = "http://localhost:57034/api/values"; //http://localhost:57035/api/values
    constructor(private http: Http){}

    getOc(){
        return this.http.get(this.url);
    }

    UpdateOc(pcname: string, obj: Oc){
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json;text/plain'});
        const body = JSON.stringify(obj);
        return this.http.put(this.url + '/' + pcname, body, {headers: headers});
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<h1>HEAVYBOOT</h1>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Поставь галку, если надо пнуть</td>
            <td>Pcname</td>
            <td>DateServer</td>
            <td>DateClient</td>
            <td>ImportTime</td>
            <td>ExportTime</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let oc of ocs">
            <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="loadTemplate(oc)"
                         [ngOutletContext]="{ $implicit: oc }">
            </ng-template>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div>{{statusMessage}}</div>

<!-- Шаблон для чтения -->
<ng-template #readonlyTemplate let-oc>
    <td>{{oc.IsComplite}}</td>
    <td>{{oc.Pcname}}</td>
    <td>{{oc.DateServer}}</td>
    <td>{{oc.DateClient}}</td>
    <td>{{oc.ImportTime}}</td>
    <td>{{oc.ExportTime}}</td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Изменить" class="btn btn-default" (click)="editOc(oc)"/>
    </td>
</ng-template>

<!-- Шаблон для редактирования -->
<ng-template #editTemplate>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk_{{editedOc.Pcname}}" [(ngModel)]="editedOc.IsComplite" class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="editedOc.Pcname" readonly disabled class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="editedOc.DateServer" readonly disabled class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="editedOc.DateClient" readonly disabled class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="editedOc.ImportTime" readonly disabled class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="editedOc.ExportTime" readonly disabled class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Пнуть" (click)="saveOc()" class="btn btn-success" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Отмена" (click)="cancel()" class="btn btn-warning" />
    </td>
</ng-template>
```

Ошибок в консоли нет

Comment: `resp.body.json()`

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас Angular 4.4, то переходите на `HttpClient`, на хабр делал перевод недавно про него, там как минимум JSON как транспорт по умолчанию, и не нужно его туда сюда переводить.

а по вашему вопросу у Вас судя по всему ошибка в том что Вы упустили **`data`**.

```
this.ocs = resp.json().data;
```

Comment: к сожалению не помогло